# Consultas multitabla en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy haciendo una consulta con MySQL donde tengo unos establecimientos y en otra tabla tengo los comentarios del establecimiento.

Esta es la consulta que hago:

```
SELECT *
FROM establecimientos
INNER JOIN comentarios ON establecimientos.id = comentarios.id_establecimiento
WHERE establecimientos.id = 30
```

Me lo muestra pero cuando la tabla `comentarios` tiene un `comentarios.id_establecimiento` igual a `establecimientos.id`. Lo que ando buscando es que aunque no haya comentarios igual me muestra los datos de la consulta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Deberás usar LEFT JOIN** para poder mostrar incluso valore nulos

Lo primero que debes hacer es sustituir `Inner Join` por `Left join` ya que este último te va a traer todos los resultados incluso si no encuentra valores coincidentes

> La diferencia es que INNER JOIN si busca coincidencias en ambas tablas; es decir todos los datos de la tabla izquierda que tiene un registro asociado con la tabla de la derecha

```
SELECT * FROM establecimientos 
LEFT JOIN comentarios 
ON establecimientos.id = comentarios.id_establecimiento 
WHERE establecimientos.id = 30;
```

**¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre `INNER JOIN` Y `LEFT JOIN`?**

1. **Inner join** de las tablas beta y gama **(son nombre de mero ejemplo)** va a retornar como resultado todas las coincidencias o intersecciones de ambas tablas
2. **Left join** En las combinaciones izquierdas se incluyen todos los registros de la primera tabla **izquierda**, aún si no hay registros  que coincidan para los registros en la segunda tabla derecha.

Comment: solucionado, muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: Disculpa amigo, algo que no me habia fijado y es que me retorna un solo comentario pero no todos los comentarios. Que puedo hacer ahi?

Comment: te retorna solo uno por que al final de la consulta le estas indicando que te muestre donde el id del establecimiento sea igual a 30

Comment: Si pero si no lo hago me retorna todos los establecimientos, pero la idea es que me muestre 1 establecimiento pero con todos los comentarios de ese mismo establecimiento que pueden ser varios.

Comment: entonces como dice en la teoría que puse si la necesidad es mostrar todos los comentarios que pertenecen solo a un establecimiento es un inner join en todo caso

Comment: Revisando, el problema se encuentra en el foreach que estoy haciendo. haciendo el `foreach ($respuesta as $row => $item){
var_dump($respuesta);
var_dump($item);
}` el var dump de respuesta me retorna todos los comentarios y el var dump de item me muestra uno solo

Comment: usas mysqli o pdo?, por lo que veo con el foreach quieres pintar algo como una tabla con los datos no?

Comment: utilizo pdo y lo realizo con php orientado a objetos

Comment: checa esta respuesta de SO en inglés

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488364/how-to-properly-use-while-loop-in-pdo-fetchall

Answer (score 2):

Lo que estás buscando es hacer un `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM establecimientos
LEFT JOIN comentarios ON establecimientos.id = comentarios.id_establecimiento
WHERE establecimientos.id = 30
```

De esta manera, aunque no existan comentarios la consulta te traerá los datos del `establecimiento` y datos nulos en `comentarios`.